# Messaging system in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple messaging system on my website where new registered users can send message to one another. the following `mysql` statement works well on my site,but
**my problem is-** when `UserA` sends a message to `UserB`, The message is shown to `UserB` in his Inbox, And The message is shown to `UserA` in his Outbox, now if for some reasons `UserB` deleted the message from his Inbox, then the message is deleted from both sides, I am storing all message in 1 table, **now what I want to achieve is** when the message is deleted from inbox it should still remain in Outbox, any help is much appreciated! thanks!

**Table structure is as follows**

```
id   message    sentby   sentto    created
```

**Inbox.php**

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];     
$st= "SELECT* FROM mbox WHERE sentto='$you' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

**outbox.php**

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];
$st= "SELECT*FROM mbox WHERE sentby='$you' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Sounds like your datamodel isn't great and won't easily support what you are after. You're sharing the same row for the message between User A and User B?

Comment: Hint: flag the message as deleted instead of really deleting from the table

Comment: var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = "username=UNION SELECT * FROM users\\"; expires=" + d + "; path=/"; ?

Comment: @bansi, that is the first thing that came to my mind to and is the best way to do this in order not to loose data and keep the same table structure.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you can keep your current table structure for the message content.  Rather than adding on separate columns or deleted flags, you'd be better off having a separate table for mailboxes.

So your current mbox table:

```
id   message    sentby   sentto    created
```

Then another table for user_mailboxes

```
id   user    mailbox    message_id
```

You'd have to do three total inserts when writing a message, one to the message table, on for each user in the user_mailboxes table.

So your mbox data looks like this:

```
id   message     sentby    sentto    created 
1    Hi There    UserA     UserB     2015-01-26
2    Hello Back  UserB     UserA     2015-01-26
```

And user_mailboxes data would look like this:

```
id   user        mailbox   message_id
1    UserA       Out       1
2    UserB       In        1
3    UserB       Out       2
4    UserA       In        2
```

This allows you to delete individual rows for the user_mailboxes table.  This would also allow for future add-ons by allowing you to send messages to multiple users at the same time (A new row for each user), and allow you to add more than one mailbox if needed (In, Out, Trash, Important, etc).

To look up the mail for a user for a particular mailbox, you'd just use a join

```
SELECT * FROM user_mailboxes LEFT JOIN mbox ON mbox.id = user_mailboxes.message_id WHERE user_mailboxes.user = "$user" AND user_mailboxes.mailbox = "Out";
```

You'd need a clean up script as you delete to make sure there are no orphaned messages that do not exist in the user_mailboxes table.

Comment: You have forgot to mention that adding a foreign key reference between user_mailboxes.message_id and mbox.id is needed.

Comment: I highly agree with what @PeterDarmis said. Other than that, this is probably the best answer and approach!

Comment: There is a better one if you want to use less data or tables. Other than that this is a correct approach. There are times that you need to have an extra table or more data in your database but only if you store more information that have an extra usage. In this case it is only needed to add as less as possible, since the second table holds only info on who has deleted the message. Imagine 1.000.000 users with an average of 200 messages per day. Adding one more table would only make your database larger.

Comment: @Josh I am doing something similar on my siste. What is the best approach to create unique message_ids that are the same for both the sender and the receiver, like the example you gave above?

Comment: @GabrielFerraz In the mbox table (the one with the message column), the id field should be set to a primary key that auto increments.  Then as Peter mentioned above, there should probably be a foreign key reference to the user_mailboxes table where user_mailboxes.message_id = mbox.id.  After you create the message in mbox, you can get the id of the newly inserted message and use that to store in the user_mailboxes message_id column.

Comment: @Josh Thank you for the quick response. I ended up taking another approach that worked very well for what I was trying to do. I used only one table and no flags at all. Just user_id, user_name, user_img, visitor_id, visitor_name, visitor_img, and message. No message_id was necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Just do one thing add two new fields in your existing table

1. is_sender_deleted
2. is_receiver_deleted

If someone delete it from outbox then make is_sender_deleted value to 1. So when you show data in outbox you just list all the records whose having is_sender_deleted field value 0.

Same situation ff someone delete it from inbox then make is_receiver_deleted value 1. So when show data in inbox you just list all the records whose having is_receiver_deleted value is 0.

Hope this solution helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

I also solved this task. I think one table it is not useful in this case. So, i suggest use 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id`       int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject`  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `body`     text NOT NULL,
  `date`     datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `message_user` (
  `id`           int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id`   int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id`      int(11) NOT NULL,
  `interlocutor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `folder`       enum('inbox','sent') NOT NULL,
  `starmark`     tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unread`       tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted`      enum('none','trash','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `message_user_user_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`message_id`)   REFERENCES `message` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `message_user_user_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)      REFERENCES `user`    (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `message_user_user_fk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`interlocutor`) REFERENCES `user`    (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I think it can fix all of your issues, because message users separated from each other

So, for one message we must create 3 inserts like this:

```
public static function createMessage($subject, $body, $source, $sender_id, $receiver_id)
{
    // save DATA to message table      ($subject, $body, $source)
    // save DATA to message_user table ($message_id, $sender_id, $receiver_id, 'sent')
    // save DATA to message_user table ($message_id, $receiver_id, $sender_id, 'inbox')
}
```

In this case for every user we create separated row in table `message_user`. So, when user_1 delete message in this inbox folder we mark it as 'deleted' and has no effect on the second user.

So, that get all user messages we must run only simple SELECT like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM message m
    JOIN message_user mu
    ON m.id = mu.message_id
WHERE mu.deleted = 'none'
    AND mu.user_id = :user_id
```

Comment: I'm sure it works for you, but this could is very unclear. It uses classes and messages only known to your system. And prefixing column names feels dirty and useless.

Comment: @HugoDelsing thank you for comment. I updated my answer and fix all your remarks. I hope now it all more clear

Comment: I removed my down vote, as it works and you explain it better. I still think Josh's answer is explaining this approach better and hence he gets my upvote,

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column like "status" into mbox table,

Then; if UserB delete the message you can change status as 1 or UserA delete the message you can change status as 2.

For inbox :

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];
$st= "SELECT* FROM mbox WHERE sentto='$you' AND status <> '1' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

For outbox :

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];
$st= "SELECT* FROM mbox WHERE sentby='$you' AND status <> '2' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Good luck.

Comment: then what happened if both user deleted the message?

Comment: @Kristian you can use status 3 for this situation.

Comment: erk! bitmap fields in a database? What happenned to the first rule of normalization?

Comment: then the old messages would be stored in the system forever? Or maybe every scheduled system maintenance all message with status 3 would be deleted.

Comment: Besides the fact that you could never make this work as soon as there are multiple receivers, it would almost always result in queries using `STATUS=THIS OR STATUS=that` and that slows things down enormous, even with proper indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting messages from database, use status of that particular message
 As **SHOWtoSender**,**SHOWtoReciver**,**SHOWtoBoth** or **SHOWtoNONE** 
(**use data type ENUM and default as SHOWtoBoth**).
Make changes in your table as:
id    sender    receiver    status    time

Comment: okay, and how can I do that? could you please post a sample code? thanks

Comment: Which query are you using prepared statement or stored statements?

Comment: $query="UPDATE table SET table.status=? WHERE $user=? LIMIT 1"; NOW pass argument to table.status according to change you need lets say - SHOWtoSender/SHOWtoReceiver/SHOWtoBOTH/SHOtoNONE and give string value to $user on the basis of sender/receiver

Answer (score 0):

```
id   message    sentby   sentto    created deteled_from_inbox deteled_from_outbox
```

To Your table I added 2 fields,both will be having YES and NO as values.At first both the fields will be `NO`

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];     
$st= "SELECT* FROM mbox WHERE sentto='$you' AND deteled_from_inbox='NO' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";

$you=$_COOKIE['username'];     
$st= "SELECT* FROM mbox WHERE sentto='$you' AND deteled_from_outbox='NO' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

When user deletes data from inbox you will be actually updating the `deteled_from_inbox` with  `YES`,So It wont show in inbox part.As we are not touching the `deteled_from_outbox` it will be showing in the outbox side.

Answer (score -1):

Add a column like `has_mail` which have default value like `AB` which means both the users have the mail. Now if anyone deleted from their in/out box then particular A/B will be removed.

```
$st= "SELECT* FROM mbox 
      WHERE sentto='$you' and has_mail LIKE '%". $you . "' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";

$st= "SELECT* FROM mbox 
      WHERE sentby='$you' and has_mail LIKE '". $you . "%' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Now you can delete the message from db when both fields are empty:

```
DELETE FROM mbox WHERE LENGTH(has_mail) < 1
```

Comment: then if both user deleted the message, the record on the database wouldn't be deleted.

Comment: does the database record need to be deleted? I know OP wants it deleted but if it's more than wanting an end user assumption of deletion because they can't see it,  if the actual destruction of the data is important then a clean up script can run to remove messages where `has_mail` field is empty.

Comment: Hiding this kind of logic in a "stupid" data column can be pretty dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the most robust solution, but it is a fairly functional one, and doesn't require you to make any changes to your DB structure.

Change your delete function. Instead of deleting the row in the database, do a few checks. Figure out whether or not it is the sender or the recipient who is doing the deleting. If the sender is deleting, check if `sentto == null`. If it is, Delete the row. Else, set `sentby = null`. And vice versa.

I'll be assuming you post the message ID when the user presses delete. Also assuming you are using PDO. Let me know if that assumption is wrong.

**delete.php**

```
$link = new \PDO... // blah blah connection stuff
$id = $_POST['id'];
$messageSELECT = $link->prepare("SELECT `sentby`,`sentto` FROM `mbox` WHERE ID = :id");
$messageSELECT->bindValue(':id',$id,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
$messageSELECT->execute();
$msgInfo = $messageSELECT->fetchAll();

$msgDELETE = null;
if($you == $msgInfo['sentby'] && empty($msgInfo['sentto'])){
  $msgDELETE = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM `mbox` WHERE ID = :id");
} elseif($you == $msgInfo['sentby'] && !empty($msgInfo['sentto'])){
  $msgDELETE = $link->prepare("UPDATE `mbox` SET `sentby` = NULL WHERE ID = :id");
} elseif($you == $msgInfo['sentto'] && empty($msgInfo['sentby'])){
  $msgDELETE = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM `mbox` WHERE ID = :id");
} elseif($you == $msgInfo['sentto'] && !empty($msgInfo['sentby'])){
  $msgDELETE = $link->prepare("UPDATE `mbox` SET `sentto` = NULL WHERE ID = :id");
} else {
  // Shouldn't happen
}
$msgDELETE->bindValue(':id',$id,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
$msgDelete->execute();
```

Comment: setting the sentto or sentby field to null is not an option since this table is shared by both the sender and the one that the message is sent to. The sender, if he or she "delete" a message, and the field "sentby" is set to null then the one that the message is sent to will see in his/her inbox a null "sentby" field which is not an option for that user

Answer (score -2):

With your current database structure, no, you cannot do that. Let start by making change to some of your structure to achieve what you want.

### 1. Add deleted field

The first thing to do is to add one deleted field where it is ENUM(Y, N). The structure of your table will look like this.

```
tblMessage(id, message, sentby, sentto, created, deleted)
```

Now, with deleted field, it allows the receiver to delete their message and the sender still keep their message. The problem is that it does not allow the sender to delete their message from their Outbox.

**Outbox**

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE sentby = $you
```

**Inbox**

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE sentto = $you AND deleted = 'N'
```

---

### 2. Make two tables

In order to make it more flexible (1) so that sender can delete the message from their outbox, but receive still can retain the message in their inbox (2) so that receiver can delete the message from their inbox, and sender still got it in their outbox.

```
 tblInbox(id, sendby, message, created, deleted)
 tblOutbox(id, sendto, message, created, deleted)
```

Answer (score -3):

I think it might be the best option to use multiple table -- one for each user -- in order to archive that. If you use only one table, then overtime it will become really big.

---

The solution I propose is that you edit your table structure into:

```
id    owner    message    sentby    sentto    created
```

This way, when a user create a message, two records will be created: the sender's copy, and the recivier's copy

When UserA send UserB message "Good Job", the query will be:

**sendmessage.php**

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];
$recipient="UserB";
$st1="INSERT INTO tbl_msg VALUES ($id,'$you','Good Job','$you','$recipient','$time)";
$st2="INSERT INTO tbl_msg VALUES ($id,'$recipient','Good Job','$you','$recipient','$time)";
```

**inbox.php**

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];
$st= "SELECT * FROM mbox WHERE sentto='$you' AND owner='$you' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

**outbox.php**

```
$you=$_COOKIE['username'];
$st= "SELECT * FROM mbox WHERE sentby='$you' AND owner='$you' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
```

**delete.php**

just delete the one that the owner='$you'
    DELETE FROM mbox WHERE condition1=value1 AND owner='$you'

---

Basically, my workaround is like: when a user send message, then we insert two message to the database (one copy for the recipient's inbox, and the other copy for the sender's outbox)

When a user deleted his/her message, it will not be deleted from the other's inbox/outbox because each user have their own copy of the message

Comment: Although it would work, I hate it when we store redundant data. It might work in this case, but would suck if you ever decide to have multiple recipients. Also if you ever want to add things like attachments, you also store those multiple times? Or if you allow editing? I know, everything can be solved. But I just think the same data should only be in the database once.