# How to delete the message received and sent by Member A from the chat without deleting it in member B's account

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table where i store the chat informations between 2 members (Member A and Member B). Now when Member A delete his messages i throw an sql request like this

```
$deleting = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM `mychattable` WHERE (`from`='$id_of_member_a' AND `to`='$id_of_member_b') OR (`from`='$id_of_member_b' AND `to`='$id_of_member_a') ") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

When i do that the problem is that it deletes the messages from both Member A and Member B's account.

I have also tried

```
$deleting = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM `mychattable` WHERE `from`='$id_of_member_b' AND `to`='$id_of_member_a' ") or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

But when i do that it deletes the messages of Member A from the database so Member B no longer has access to it

How to delete the message received and sent by Member A from the chat without deleting it in member B's account ?

This is the structure of my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mychattable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `read` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `direction` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `to` (`to`),
  KEY `from` (`from`),
  KEY `direction` (`direction`),
  KEY `read` (`read`),
  KEY `sent` (`sent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;
```

Thanks

Comment: is there a foreign key dependency in the other table that we don't know about?

Comment: @RamRaider No it is only one table named mychattable. And above is it's structure

Comment: Check out this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752062/messaging-system-in-php-mysql  May be there is your solution!

Comment: @student I have checked your answer but it does not completely satisfy my needs because it implies a double insert, an insertion in two different tables

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new column named 'status'. do not run delete query and just change the status form 0:visible to 1:invisible for the message. and when user B wants to check it then put condition which allows him to see even when status is '1' for the message.

Comment: I have done that but the problem is that what happens when Member B also decides to delete the message. If member A has deleted the message for example and i have turned status value to 1, what happens when Member B also decides to delete the message ?

Comment: in that case u can create status for both the sender and reciever... flag_sender and flag_reciever.. change the status accordingly as per ur requirement.... and would be easy to manage....