# Foreach statement in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql

I trying to implement the following:
The messaging idea was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28156518/1491063)

I have a message box table:

```
mbox

id | message | sentby | sentto |
1    hello      1        2
```

and a user mailboxes (mailbox 0 is for incoming, 1 for outgoing)

```
user_mailboxes

id | user | mailbox | message_id
1    1       1         1
2    2       0         1
```

I have created a trigger:

```
INSERT INTO user_mailboxes (user,mailbox,message_id) 
VALUES (NEW.sentto,0,NEW.id),(NEW.sentby,1,NEW.id)
```

By doing this, i only have to worry inserting via PHP into mbox and mysql does the rest (inserting into `user_mailboxes`).

This is working for single recipient, sending messages to a single user.

What if i want to multiple recipients? For example, the `sentto` value could be an array [1,4,6,10].

Is there any way to rewrite the mysql trigger to perform a loop with the `sentto` values? This could save me a lot time rewriting the php code.

Something like this(pseudo code):

```
FOR EACH sentto as SOME_VALUE;
  INSERT INTO user_mailboxes (user,mailbox,message_id) 
  VALUES (SOME_VALUE,0,NEW.id),(NEW.sentby,1,NEW.id)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think in this case you also have to insert that message for all the recipients right? then the trigger will work as per your requirement;

Comment: itzmukeshy7 i am inserting the message once and then when i want to fetch the mesages per user,  i look at user_mailboxes and JOIN the message, title, date etc from mbox. Inserting the same message in mbox multiple times would be waste of time, space and performance and also then the above solution would be redundant.

Comment: Then you should use junction table and insert messages in a table and save reference in other table in that you don't have to insert a same message multiple time for the sender as well as recipient;